# How do I find the B matrix of $T_k$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I'm very confused because this problem doesn't give specific matrices but has a function in it.

Comment: The functions are polynomials here. You are in the space $P_2$ of all polynomials with degree at most $2$. In this space you can add, subtract and multiply with numbers. So, it is a vector space. It is spanned by the vectors (polynomials) $1$, $t$, and $t^2$ because you can write any polynomial in $P_2$ as a linear combination of those three. As the first step, you have to evaluate $T_k$ at $1$, $t$, and $t^2$. For example, we have $T_k(t^2) = 2 + kt^2$ because when you derive $t^2$ twice, you get $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, in order to find the representation matrix we need to do two things.

- Express $T_k(1), T_k(t), T_k(t^2)$ in terms of $1,t,t^2$. For example, applying the transformation $T$ to the function $f(t) = 1$, we have: $$T_k(1) = 1'' + k\cdot 1 = 0 + k = k\cdot \color{blue}{1} + 0 \cdot \color{blue}{t} + 0\cdot \color{blue}{t^2}.$$
  I guess now you can find $T_k(t), T_k(t^2)$.
- The coefficients above are going to be the columns of the matrix $B$, i.e.
  $$B = \begin{bmatrix} k & * & * \\ 0 & * & *\\ 0 & * & * \end{bmatrix}$$

Analyzing $T_k(t), T_k(t^2)$ in terms of $1,t,t^2$ and getting the coefficients, we can define completely matrix $B$.

But what is the meaning of the transformation matrix? The following equality.
$[1 \quad t \quad t^2]\cdot \begin{bmatrix} k & * & * \\ 0 & * & *\\ 0 & * & * \end{bmatrix} = [T_k(1) \quad T_k(t) \quad T_k(t^2)]$, which means we apply the transformation $T_k$ to each of the functions $1,t,t^2$.

---

P.S. Feel free to ask if you have any question.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you have the general equation of the linear mapping, that is the function has an associated matrix for it and maps to its own space. Use the standard basis provided $\beta$ to express any combination as a unique choice of coefficients for the basis $\beta$ that spans $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and write them as column vectors in the associated matrix.